# How safe is it if encrypted text is exposed?

Tags: encryption

I know that it is considered safe if both encryption algorithm and password are safely hidden. However, what if the attacker knows that there can only be a number of algorithms used. So how safe is it in this case?

Is it bad practice to include encrypted text in source control?

Comment: Good crypto design assumes the encryption algorithm is public and _only_ the key is kept secret.

Answer (score 3):

If you are encrypting a client secret where it needs to be decrypted and used to access another service, you should not expose this to any untrusted system, including checking in to source control, as that would mean that people with access to the system would be able to get access to the secret.

Also other automated processes which work off the source code repository (for example code review tools) would get access, so you could end up with the secret being known quite widely which is rarely a good idea.

One way to approach managing this kind of secret is to store them separately during development and then inject them at deployment.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, by password I mean, client_secret, client_id, etc. Updated to "encrypted text"

Comment: People who have access access to repo would only have access to the encrypted texts. Can you elaborate more on "get access to the secret"? because without knowing the encryption algo and password, how is it possible?

Comment: so if you have a secret in the code repo. you presumably also have the code.  the code must include a method for decrypting the secret (otherwise it's unsuable).  so someone with access to the code has both the secret and the means to decrypt it.

Comment: not if the encryption password and the algorithm name are hidden...

Comment: ok, so I'm assuming that the application has to be able to decrypt the client key?  If the code to decrypt the key and the key itself are contained in the source code repository why would someone who can see the repository not be able to just read the code and then use it to decrypt the key?

Comment: the algorithm used would presumably be named in the source code. and presumably any password required to decrypt the key is also there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26958/discussion-between-bpm-and-rry-mccune).